# React ant deisgn Form data search conflict

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

I'm beginner to react and I'm using `ant design` for my application. Here is my conflict,  I'm trying to make book name and price search after display details, but I don't know how to do that correctly.
Anyone know how to do that correctly?

**[stazkblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ghvwxl-wqaxcw?file=index.js)**

**code here**

```
    <div>
      <Row justify="center">
        <Col span={24}>
          <Card title="Search Book" >
            <Row >
              <Col span={6}>
                <Input placeholder="Book Name" />  <Space></Space>
              </Col>

              <Col span={6}><Input placeholder="Price" /></Col>
              <Col span={6}>
              <Button type="primary" icon={<SearchOutlined />}>
                Search
              </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <br/><br/>
              
            <Descriptions title="Book Info">
              <Descriptions.Item label="Book Name">{this.bookName}</Descriptions.Item>
              <Descriptions.Item label="Price">{this.bookPrice}</Descriptions.Item>
            </Descriptions>

          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
```

Comment: I just updated your code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ghvwxl-sycabk?file=index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple working example should give you an idea about filtering and search into the array of objects using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const { Input, Card, Row, Col, Space, Button, Descriptions } = antd

const books = [
  { name: "example1", price: 1 },
  { name: "example2", price: 2 },
  { name: "example3", price: 3 },
  { name: "example4", price: 4 },
  { name: "example11", price: 10 },
  { name: "example20", price: 20 },
  { name: "example34", price: 30 },
  { name: "example48", price: 40 },
];
const App = () => {
  const [filteredBooks, setFilteredBooks] = React.useState(books);
  const bookHandler = e => {
    setFilteredBooks(books.filter(book => (
      book.name.includes(e.target.value)))
    )
  };
  const priceHandler = e => {
    if(e.target.value)
      setFilteredBooks(books.filter(book => (
        book.price <= Number(e.target.value)))
      )
    else setFilteredBooks(books)
  };
  return (
    <Card>
      <Row>
      <Descriptions title="Filter:"/>
        <Col span={6}>
          <Input type="text" placeholder="Book Name" onChange={bookHandler} />
          <Space />
        </Col>
        <Col span={6}>
          <Input type="number" placeholder="Price" onChange={priceHandler} />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <br />
      {filteredBooks.map(book => (
        <Descriptions title="Book Info">
          <Descriptions.Item label="Book Name">
            {book.name}
          </Descriptions.Item>
          <Descriptions.Item label="Price">
            {book.price}
          </Descriptions.Item>
        </Descriptions>
      ))}
    </Card>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.10.3/antd.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/4.10.3/antd.min.css"/>
<div id="react"></div>
```